# Three.js OrbitControls Orthographic Panning

Tags: javascript, three.js, pan, orthographic

In my program, the further out you zoom, the slower you can pan around. So, I want to increase the panning speed based on the zoom level. I've tried .panSpeed, but that doesn't work, and .panSpeed doesn't seem to exist anymore in OrbitControls.js. Is there another function that I can use?

Here is the documentation I looked at for Three.js OrbitControls:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Comment: This issue was fixed in three.js r.75. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8340

Comment: Thank you, WestLangley!!

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the documentation you just linked youll'find

```
// Set to false to disable panning
this.enablePan = true;
this.keyPanSpeed = 7.0; // pixels moved per arrow key push
```

Maybe .keyPanSpeed is what you're looking for.

**UPDATE 1:**
In the OrbitControls.js you have the following function to handle pan:

```
function pan( deltaX, deltaY ) {

        var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

        constraint.pan( deltaX, deltaY, element.clientWidth, element.clientHeight );

    }
```

So if for example you multiply deltaX and deltaY by 10 you'll see the pan going 10 times faster:

```
constraint.pan( deltaX * 10, deltaY * 10, element.clientWidth, element.clientHeight );
```

Try to insert your calculations based on zoom right there, it should work.

**UPDATE 2:**
Actually I'm using an older version of OrbitControls, which is slightly different from the current one. Here it is:

```
    /**
 * @author qiao / https://github.com/qiao
 * @author mrdoob / http://mrdoob.com
 * @author alteredq / http://alteredqualia.com/
 * @author WestLangley / http://github.com/WestLangley
 * @author erich666 / http://erichaines.com
 */
/*global THREE, console */

( function () {

function OrbitConstraint ( object ) {

    this.object = object;

    // "target" sets the location of focus, where the object orbits around
    // and where it pans with respect to.
    this.target = new THREE.Vector3();

    // Limits to how far you can dolly in and out ( PerspectiveCamera only )
    this.minDistance = 0;
    this.maxDistance = Infinity;

    // Limits to how far you can zoom in and out ( OrthographicCamera only )
    this.minZoom = 0;
    this.maxZoom = Infinity;

    // How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
    // Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
    this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
    this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

    // How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
    // If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
    this.minAzimuthAngle = - Infinity; // radians
    this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians

    // Set to true to enable damping (inertia)
    // If damping is enabled, you must call controls.update() in your animation loop
    this.enableDamping = false;
    this.dampingFactor = 0.25;

    ////////////
    // internals

    var scope = this;

    var EPS = 0.000001;

    // Current position in spherical coordinate system.
    var theta;
    var phi;

    // Pending changes
    var phiDelta = 0;
    var thetaDelta = 0;
    var scale = 1;
    var panOffset = new THREE.Vector3();
    var zoomChanged = false;

    // API

    this.getPolarAngle = function () {

        return phi;

    };

    this.getAzimuthalAngle = function () {

        return theta;

    };

    this.rotateLeft = function ( angle ) {

        thetaDelta -= angle;

    };

    this.rotateUp = function ( angle ) {

        phiDelta -= angle;

    };

    // pass in distance in world space to move left
    this.panLeft = function() {

        var v = new THREE.Vector3();

        return function panLeft ( distance ) {

            var te = this.object.matrix.elements;

            // get X column of matrix
            v.set( te[ 0 ], te[ 1 ], te[ 2 ] );
            v.multiplyScalar( - distance );

            panOffset.add( v );

        };

    }();

    // pass in distance in world space to move up
    this.panUp = function() {

        var v = new THREE.Vector3();

        return function panUp ( distance ) {

            var te = this.object.matrix.elements;

            // get Y column of matrix
            v.set( te[ 4 ], te[ 5 ], te[ 6 ] );
            v.multiplyScalar( distance );

            panOffset.add( v );

        };

    }();

    // pass in x,y of change desired in pixel space,
    // right and down are positive
    this.pan = function ( deltaX, deltaY, screenWidth, screenHeight ) {

        if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

            // perspective
            var position = scope.object.position;
            var offset = position.clone().sub( scope.target );
            var targetDistance = offset.length();

            // half of the fov is center to top of screen
            targetDistance *= Math.tan( ( scope.object.fov / 2 ) * Math.PI / 180.0 );

            // we actually don't use screenWidth, since perspective camera is fixed to screen height
            scope.panLeft( 2 * deltaX * targetDistance / screenHeight );
            scope.panUp( 2 * deltaY * targetDistance / screenHeight );

        } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

            // orthographic
            scope.panLeft( deltaX * ( scope.object.right - scope.object.left ) / screenWidth );
            scope.panUp( deltaY * ( scope.object.top - scope.object.bottom ) / screenHeight );

        } else {

            // camera neither orthographic or perspective
            console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - pan disabled.' );

        }

    };

    this.dollyIn = function ( dollyScale ) {

        if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

            scale /= dollyScale;

        } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

            scope.object.zoom = Math.max( this.minZoom, Math.min( this.maxZoom, this.object.zoom * dollyScale ) );
            scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
            zoomChanged = true;

        } else {

            console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - dolly/zoom disabled.' );

        }

    };

    this.dollyOut = function ( dollyScale ) {

        if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

            scale *= dollyScale;

        } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

            scope.object.zoom = Math.max( this.minZoom, Math.min( this.maxZoom, this.object.zoom / dollyScale ) );
            scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
            zoomChanged = true;

        } else {

            console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - dolly/zoom disabled.' );

        }

    };

    this.update = function() {

        var offset = new THREE.Vector3();

        // so camera.up is the orbit axis
        var quat = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors( object.up, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ) );
        var quatInverse = quat.clone().inverse();

        var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
        var lastQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

        return function () {

            var position = this.object.position;

            offset.copy( position ).sub( this.target );

            // rotate offset to "y-axis-is-up" space
            offset.applyQuaternion( quat );

            // angle from z-axis around y-axis

            theta = Math.atan2( offset.x, offset.z );

            // angle from y-axis

            phi = Math.atan2( Math.sqrt( offset.x * offset.x + offset.z * offset.z ), offset.y );

            theta += thetaDelta;
            phi += phiDelta;

            // restrict theta to be between desired limits
            theta = Math.max( this.minAzimuthAngle, Math.min( this.maxAzimuthAngle, theta ) );

            // restrict phi to be between desired limits
            phi = Math.max( this.minPolarAngle, Math.min( this.maxPolarAngle, phi ) );

            // restrict phi to be betwee EPS and PI-EPS
            phi = Math.max( EPS, Math.min( Math.PI - EPS, phi ) );

            var radius = offset.length() * scale;

            // restrict radius to be between desired limits
            radius = Math.max( this.minDistance, Math.min( this.maxDistance, radius ) );

            // move target to panned location
            this.target.add( panOffset );

            offset.x = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
            offset.y = radius * Math.cos( phi );
            offset.z = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );

            // rotate offset back to "camera-up-vector-is-up" space
            offset.applyQuaternion( quatInverse );

            position.copy( this.target ).add( offset );

            this.object.lookAt( this.target );

            if ( this.enableDamping === true ) {

                thetaDelta *= ( 1 - this.dampingFactor );
                phiDelta *= ( 1 - this.dampingFactor );

            } else {

                thetaDelta = 0;
                phiDelta = 0;

            }

            scale = 1;
            panOffset.set( 0, 0, 0 );

            // update condition is:
            // min(camera displacement, camera rotation in radians)^2 > EPS
            // using small-angle approximation cos(x/2) = 1 - x^2 / 8

            if ( zoomChanged ||
                 lastPosition.distanceToSquared( this.object.position ) > EPS ||
                8 * ( 1 - lastQuaternion.dot( this.object.quaternion ) ) > EPS ) {

                lastPosition.copy( this.object.position );
                lastQuaternion.copy( this.object.quaternion );
                zoomChanged = false;

                return true;

            }

            return false;

        };

    }();

};


// This set of controls performs orbiting, dollying (zooming), and panning. It maintains
// the "up" direction as +Y, unlike the TrackballControls. Touch on tablet and phones is
// supported.
//
//    Orbit - left mouse / touch: one finger move
//    Zoom - middle mouse, or mousewheel / touch: two finger spread or squish
//    Pan - right mouse, or arrow keys / touch: three finter swipe

THREE.OrbitControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

    var constraint = new OrbitConstraint( object );

    this.domElement = ( domElement !== undefined ) ? domElement : document;

    // API

    Object.defineProperty( this, 'constraint', {

        get: function() {

            return constraint;

        }

    } );

    this.getPolarAngle = function () {

        return constraint.getPolarAngle();

    };

    this.getAzimuthalAngle = function () {

        return constraint.getAzimuthalAngle();

    };

    // Set to false to disable this control
    this.enabled = true;

    // center is old, deprecated; use "target" instead
    this.center = this.target;

    // This option actually enables dollying in and out; left as "zoom" for
    // backwards compatibility.
    // Set to false to disable zooming
    this.enableZoom = true;
    this.zoomSpeed = 1.0;

    // Set to false to disable rotating
    this.enableRotate = true;
    this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;

    // Set to false to disable panning
    this.enablePan = true;
    this.keyPanSpeed = 7.0; // pixels moved per arrow key push

    // Set to true to automatically rotate around the target
    // If auto-rotate is enabled, you must call controls.update() in your animation loop
    this.autoRotate = false;
    this.autoRotateSpeed = 2.0; // 30 seconds per round when fps is 60

    // Set to false to disable use of the keys
    this.enableKeys = true;

    // The four arrow keys
    this.keys = { LEFT: 37, UP: 38, RIGHT: 39, BOTTOM: 40 };

    // Mouse buttons
    this.mouseButtons = { ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, PAN: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT };

    ////////////
    // internals

    var scope = this;

    var rotateStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var rotateEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var rotateDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    var panStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var panEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var panDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    var dollyStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var dollyEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var dollyDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    var STATE = { NONE : - 1, ROTATE : 0, DOLLY : 1, PAN : 2, TOUCH_ROTATE : 3, TOUCH_DOLLY : 4, TOUCH_PAN : 5 };

    var state = STATE.NONE;

    // for reset

    this.target0 = this.target.clone();
    this.position0 = this.object.position.clone();
    this.zoom0 = this.object.zoom;

    // events

    var changeEvent = { type: 'change' };
    var startEvent = { type: 'start' };
    var endEvent = { type: 'end' };

    // pass in x,y of change desired in pixel space,
    // right and down are positive
    function pan( deltaX, deltaY ) {

        var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

        constraint.pan( deltaX, deltaY, element.clientWidth, element.clientHeight );

    }

    this.update = function () {

        if ( this.autoRotate && state === STATE.NONE ) {

            constraint.rotateLeft( getAutoRotationAngle() );

        }

        if ( constraint.update() === true ) {

            this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

        }

    };

    this.reset = function () {

        state = STATE.NONE;

        this.target.copy( this.target0 );
        this.object.position.copy( this.position0 );
        this.object.zoom = this.zoom0;

        this.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
        this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

        this.update();

    };

    function getAutoRotationAngle() {

        return 2 * Math.PI / 60 / 60 * scope.autoRotateSpeed;

    }

    function getZoomScale() {

        return Math.pow( 0.95, scope.zoomSpeed );

    }

    function onMouseDown( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.ORBIT ) {

            if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

            state = STATE.ROTATE;

            rotateStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

        } else if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.ZOOM ) {

            if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

            state = STATE.DOLLY;

            dollyStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

        } else if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.PAN ) {

            if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

            state = STATE.PAN;

            panStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

        }

        if ( state !== STATE.NONE ) {

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );
            scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

        }

    }

    function onMouseMove( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        event.preventDefault();

        var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

        if ( state === STATE.ROTATE ) {

            if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

            rotateEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
            rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

            // rotating across whole screen goes 360 degrees around
            constraint.rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed );

            // rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180
            constraint.rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed );

            rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

        } else if ( state === STATE.DOLLY ) {

            if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

            dollyEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
            dollyDelta.subVectors( dollyEnd, dollyStart );

            if ( dollyDelta.y > 0 ) {

                constraint.dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

            } else if ( dollyDelta.y < 0 ) {

                constraint.dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

            }

            dollyStart.copy( dollyEnd );

        } else if ( state === STATE.PAN ) {

            if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

            panEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
            panDelta.subVectors( panEnd, panStart );

            pan( panDelta.x, panDelta.y );

            panStart.copy( panEnd );

        }

        if ( state !== STATE.NONE ) scope.update();

    }

    function onMouseUp( /* event */ ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );
        scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );
        state = STATE.NONE;

    }

    function onMouseWheel( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false || scope.enableZoom === false || state !== STATE.NONE ) return;

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        var delta = 0;

        if ( event.wheelDelta !== undefined ) {

            // WebKit / Opera / Explorer 9

            delta = event.wheelDelta;

        } else if ( event.detail !== undefined ) {

            // Firefox

            delta = - event.detail;

        }

        if ( delta > 0 ) {

            constraint.dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

        } else if ( delta < 0 ) {

            constraint.dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

        }

        scope.update();
        scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent );
        scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

    }

    function onKeyDown( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false || scope.enableKeys === false || scope.enablePan === false ) return;

        switch ( event.keyCode ) {

            case scope.keys.UP:
                pan( 0, scope.keyPanSpeed );
                scope.update();
                break;

            case scope.keys.BOTTOM:
                pan( 0, - scope.keyPanSpeed );
                scope.update();
                break;

            case scope.keys.LEFT:
                pan( scope.keyPanSpeed, 0 );
                scope.update();
                break;

            case scope.keys.RIGHT:
                pan( - scope.keyPanSpeed, 0 );
                scope.update();
                break;

        }

    }

    function touchstart( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        switch ( event.touches.length ) {

            case 1: // one-fingered touch: rotate

                if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

                state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;

                rotateStart.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );
                break;

            case 2: // two-fingered touch: dolly

                if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

                state = STATE.TOUCH_DOLLY;

                var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
                var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
                var distance = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );
                dollyStart.set( 0, distance );
                break;

            case 3: // three-fingered touch: pan

                if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

                state = STATE.TOUCH_PAN;

                panStart.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );
                break;

            default:

                state = STATE.NONE;

        }

        if ( state !== STATE.NONE ) scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

    }

    function touchmove( event ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

        switch ( event.touches.length ) {

            case 1: // one-fingered touch: rotate

                if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;
                if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE ) return;

                rotateEnd.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );
                rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

                // rotating across whole screen goes 360 degrees around
                constraint.rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed );
                // rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180
                constraint.rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed );

                rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

                scope.update();
                break;

            case 2: // two-fingered touch: dolly

                if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;
                if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_DOLLY ) return;

                var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
                var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
                var distance = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

                dollyEnd.set( 0, distance );
                dollyDelta.subVectors( dollyEnd, dollyStart );

                if ( dollyDelta.y > 0 ) {

                    constraint.dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

                } else if ( dollyDelta.y < 0 ) {

                    constraint.dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

                }

                dollyStart.copy( dollyEnd );

                scope.update();
                break;

            case 3: // three-fingered touch: pan

                if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;
                if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_PAN ) return;

                panEnd.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );
                panDelta.subVectors( panEnd, panStart );

                pan( panDelta.x, panDelta.y );

                panStart.copy( panEnd );

                scope.update();
                break;

            default:

                state = STATE.NONE;

        }

    }

    function touchend( /* event */ ) {

        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );
        state = STATE.NONE;

    }

    function contextmenu( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

    }

    this.dispose = function() {

        this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'contextmenu', contextmenu, false );
        this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
        this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
        this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'MozMousePixelScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox

        this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
        this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchend', touchend, false );
        this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );

        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );

        window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

    }

    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', contextmenu, false );

    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'MozMousePixelScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox

    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchend', touchend, false );
    this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );

    window.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

    // force an update at start
    this.update();

};

THREE.OrbitControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );
THREE.OrbitControls.prototype.constructor = THREE.OrbitControls;

Object.defineProperties( THREE.OrbitControls.prototype, {

    object: {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.object;

        }

    },

    target: {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.target;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: target is now immutable. Use target.set() instead.' );
            this.constraint.target.copy( value );

        }

    },

    minDistance : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.minDistance;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.minDistance = value;

        }

    },

    maxDistance : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.maxDistance;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.maxDistance = value;

        }

    },

    minZoom : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.minZoom;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.minZoom = value;

        }

    },

    maxZoom : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.maxZoom;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.maxZoom = value;

        }

    },

    minPolarAngle : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.minPolarAngle;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.minPolarAngle = value;

        }

    },

    maxPolarAngle : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.maxPolarAngle;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.maxPolarAngle = value;

        }

    },

    minAzimuthAngle : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.minAzimuthAngle;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.minAzimuthAngle = value;

        }

    },

    maxAzimuthAngle : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.maxAzimuthAngle;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.maxAzimuthAngle = value;

        }

    },

    enableDamping : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.enableDamping;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.enableDamping = value;

        }

    },

    dampingFactor : {

        get: function () {

            return this.constraint.dampingFactor;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            this.constraint.dampingFactor = value;

        }

    },

    // backward compatibility

    noZoom: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noZoom has been deprecated. Use .enableZoom instead.' );
            return ! this.enableZoom;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noZoom has been deprecated. Use .enableZoom instead.' );
            this.enableZoom = ! value;

        }

    },

    noRotate: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noRotate has been deprecated. Use .enableRotate instead.' );
            return ! this.enableRotate;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noRotate has been deprecated. Use .enableRotate instead.' );
            this.enableRotate = ! value;

        }

    },

    noPan: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noPan has been deprecated. Use .enablePan instead.' );
            return ! this.enablePan;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noPan has been deprecated. Use .enablePan instead.' );
            this.enablePan = ! value;

        }

    },

    noKeys: {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noKeys has been deprecated. Use .enableKeys instead.' );
            return ! this.enableKeys;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noKeys has been deprecated. Use .enableKeys instead.' );
            this.enableKeys = ! value;

        }

    },

    staticMoving : {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .staticMoving has been deprecated. Use .enableDamping instead.' );
            return ! this.constraint.enableDamping;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .staticMoving has been deprecated. Use .enableDamping instead.' );
            this.constraint.enableDamping = ! value;

        }

    },

    dynamicDampingFactor : {

        get: function () {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .dynamicDampingFactor has been renamed. Use .dampingFactor instead.' );
            return this.constraint.dampingFactor;

        },

        set: function ( value ) {

            console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .dynamicDampingFactor has been renamed. Use .dampingFactor instead.' );
            this.constraint.dampingFactor = value;

        }

    }

} );

}() );
```

Comment: keyPanSpeed only works with the arrow keys and not with the mouse. :(

Comment: @Emily Added the version of OrbitControls.js I've tested on